# Create a Couchbase Document without Specifying an ID

Tags: groovy, couchbase

Is it possible to insert a new document into a Couchbase bucket without specifying the document's ID?  I would like use Couchbase's Java SDK create a document and have Couchbase determine the document's UUID with Groovy code similar to the following:

```
import com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster
import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument

// Connect to localhost
CouchbaseCluster myCluster = CouchbaseCluster.create()

// Connect to a specific bucket
Bucket myBucket = myCluster.openBucket("default")

// Build the document
JsonObject person = JsonObject.empty()
    .put("firstname", "Stephen")
    .put("lastname", "Curry")
    .put("twitterHandle", "@StephenCurry30")
    .put("title", "First Unanimous NBA MVP)

// Create the document
JsonDocument stored = myBucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create(person));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no way to have Couchbase generate the document IDs for me.   At the suggestion of another developer, I am using `UUID.randomUUID()` to generate the document IDs in my application.  The approach is working well for me so far.

Reference:  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/create-a-couchbase-document-without-specifying-an-id/8243/4

Answer (score 1):

No, Couchbase documents have to have a key, that's the whole point of a key-value store, after all. However, if you don't care what the key is, for example, because you retrieve documents through queries rather than by key, you can just use a uuid or any other unique value when creating the document.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  To clarify, I was not trying to avoid assigning an ID to a document.  I was simply trying to see if there is a way to have Couchbase manage the IDs for me (similarly to how Elasticsearch automatically assigns a UUID to a document by default).

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, generating a UUID is one approach.

If you want to generate a more meaningful ID, for instance a "foo" prefix followed by a sequence number, you can make use of atomic counters in Couchbase.

The atomic counter is a document that contains a long, on which the SDK relies to guarantee a unique, incremented value each time you call `bucket.counter("counterKey", 1, 2)`. This code would take the value of the counter document "counterKey", increment it by 1 atomically and return the incremented value. If the counter doesn't exist, it is created with the initial value 2, which is the value returned.

This is not automatic, but a Couchbase way of creating sequences / IDs.

Comment: Thank you, @Simon.  I may incorporate counters into my application.